# Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I’ve recently updated to v14 of discordjs (I think), and I’ve been getting tons of errors as this being one of many. And it seems a lot of stuff has changed since the last time I coded and I’m a bit confused about what I need to change in order for this ping slash command to work.

**Error**
`Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead`

**Code**

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Displays Crimson's API and Latency ping!",
  options: null,
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {    
    const pingEmbed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("Pinging...")
      .setColor("#fb644c");

    const pingMsg = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [pingEmbed1], fetchReply: true });

    try {      
      const pingEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Pong!")
        .setDescription(`⌛ Latency: \`${Math.floor(pingMsg.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp)}ms\`\n⏲️ API: \`${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms\``)
        .setFooter(`Command Requested by: ${interaction.user.tag}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor("#fb644c");
      await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [pingEmbed2] });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return interaction.editReply(`\`${err.message}\`.`);
    }
  },
};
```

Now just to be clear, so people don’t get mad at me for not trying… I did change a few things that were changed such as the new embed builder and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In discord.js v14, `EmbedBuilder#setFooter()` accepts a sole `FooterOptions` object. You will need to provide an object with a `text` and an `iconURL` keys:

```js
const pingEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Pong!')
  .setDescription(
    `⌛ Latency: \`${Math.floor(
      pingMsg.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp,
    )}ms\`\n⏲️ API: \`${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms\``,
  )
  .setFooter({
    text: `Command Requested by: ${interaction.user.tag}`,
    iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
  })
  .setColor('#fb644c');
```